# Changing python3 versiosns

Tags: python-3.x, apt

I am trying to upgrade from python3.2 to python3.3 but I want it to run under the command python3 not python3.3

I have tried using apt-get to remove python3 and python3.2 but they all still seem to be present. Any ideas?

Thanks
Tom

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove --purge ...`. If anything left, it is likely a bug

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux I think all they want to do is type two less characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can creake a link from one file to another using `ln`:

```
ln /path/to/python3.3 python3
```

Now you can run `python3.3` or `python3` to do the same thing. Note that many people insist on using the `-s` flag; making the link symbolic. Note that removing Python entirely will break many Linux distributions; specifically Debian-based (Ubuntu) installations. Please also note that reinstalling or upgrading any software which uses the file name `python3` within the same "binary" directory will likely replace your link.

Your best and safer bet is to create a script or link within your local directory.

If you have any questions, please feel free to comment them.